# Access smarty variables: smarty 3.1.12

Tags: php, variables, smarty, smarty3

I am using smarty 3.1.12 for templating, however in my php files i am tryig to access my smarty variables. All my research has returned answers only for previous versions of smarty.

Comment: The smarty documentation is good place to start looking, http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
$myVars = $this->get_template_vars(); 
$this->assign('myVars',$myVars); 
{foreach from=$myVars key=k item=i} 
{$k}: {$i}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

in php file:

```
$smarty->assign('myVars',$myVars);
```

in tpl file:

```
{$myVars}
```

or:

```
{foreach $myVars as $k=>$var}
{$var}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myVar = $SMARTY->getTemplateVars('myVar');
```

Use this method for your smarty version 3.1.12